# Proving Expected Value is Maximum of this Probability Function

Tags: probability

Suppose we had m many dice each of which had n many sides. If we roll the m dice, then the probability that k of those dice have the same face value of, say r, where $1 \leq r \leq n$, should be

$$\left[(n-1)^{m-k} \binom m k \right]/n^m.$$

So I was looking for what value k maximizes this probability and through some trials it looks like it is when $k=m/n$, or rather the closest integer to $m/n$.

After looking this up (I have never formally taken stats or prob theory), I read that $m/n$ is the expected value. This makes sense, but I was hoping someone could provide an intuitive derivation or proof that the expected value is indeed $m/n$ and why it does maximize the probability.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Of note: the likeliest outcome (i.e. the *modal* outcome) and the expected value are often different from one another -- but they happen to be the same here. I'll give intuitive explanations for each; if you'd prefer rigorous proofs, let me know.

**Modal outcome**: The likeliest outcomes are the ones that have the greatest number of distinct ways of happening; for instance, if we roll three six-sided dice, there is just one way to get all threes ($[3,3,3]$), but there are six ways to get a one, a three, and a five $([1,3,5], [1,5,3], [3,1,5], [3,5,1], [5,1,3], [5,3,1])$. The most repetitions are possible when the numbers are as distinct as possible; that is, the "ideal" state is that the $m$ dice will be roughly evenly distributed into the $n$ different possibilities. If you're distributing $m$ dice into $n$ different buckets relatively evenly, you'd expect around $m/n$ dice in each bucket.

**Expected value**: Consider just a single die; it has a $1/n$ chance of being any distinct number. Since expectation is linear, and this probability is just the expected value of the indicator that die $i$ is equal to value $r$, the same will be true of each die and the full expected value will be $\frac 1 n + \frac 1 n + \dots + \frac 1 n$, repeated $m$ times; this sum is $m/n$.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! This makes a ton of sense. Now at the risk of seeming too greedy, may I ask for a rigorous proof? 

In a way, I wanted to “take the derivative” of the function and set it to zero to find the maximum, but seeing that it is a discrete valued function, that is beyond what I know how to do. Is this even a fruitful way of thinking about it? Thank you again very much for your response by the way.

Comment: Sure thing! The derivative idea is fine, but it gets tricky with the combinatorial parts; you may want to use Stirling's approximation, which states that $x! \sim x^x e^{-x} \sqrt{ 2\pi x}$, and the note that what you have is a perfectly good continuous function.

Comment: The other thing that might help with the derivative is to take a logarithm of the expression; note that since $\log(x)$ is an increasing function, $f(x)$ maximizes precisely where $\log(f(x))$ maximizes.

Comment: Ah hah! This is all so interesting. You have just given me an activity to do for the rest of the day. In all honesty, I anticipate I will get stuck and seek your council again, but not before I put some effort into your awesome suggestions. This is the drawback of doing a full year of grad algebra and not maintaining analysis skills lol. Again, I am very grateful for you help here friend. Thank you!